# Вставить текст в input

Tags: javascript

Есть сайт с формой, в этой форме несколько `input`ов с `type="text"`
Я пытаюсь сделать для этой формы автозаполнение через консоль моей инфой, использую

```
document.getElementById('NAME').value="Олег";
```

Текст в этом `input`е меняется, но сайт это игнорирует, и использует то, что было до изменений. При этом, если вручную отредактировать текст (например на "Олег1"), то эти изменения сайт воспринимает

Уже пробовал и `innerHTML`, и прочее, и `.focus()` (который не срабатывает), и вызывал событие клика через `.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'))`, ничего не срабатывает

Сам сайт кидать бессмысленно, ибо до формы ещё нужно добраться, но какие есть предположения, что можно ещё сделать?

Comment: Выяснить, какие обработчики событий назначены этому инпуту - `input`, `keypress`, `change`, и куда сохраняются данные, когда эти обработчики вызываются.

Comment: @Igor Спасибо, помог вызов `document.getElementById('NAME').dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выяснить, какие обработчики событий назначены этому инпуту - `input`, `keypress`, `change`, и куда сохраняются данные, когда эти обработчики вызываются.